# What syntax for including sub-packages in <context:component-scan>?

Tags: java, spring

I am using Spring and I have a long list of subpackages, do I have to specify them one by one in the `<context:component-scan>` tag?

```xml
<context:component-scan base-package="com.fooapp.mainpackage, 
com.fooapp.mainpackage.subpackage1, 
com.fooapp.mainpackage.subpackage2, 
com.fooapp.mainpackage.subpackage3" />
```

Answer (score 25):

Component-scanning supports package hierarchies, so this should work:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.fooapp.mainpackage"/>
```

This is easy and quicker to verify for yourself - did you try it?

Comment: very true but if you want to differentiate based on layers than you can always do `<context:component-scan base-package="com.fooapp.mainpackage.service"/> and so on for other layers`, just a thought

Comment: Based on this docs [Spring Beans and dependency injection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html), so we need to put our code (which we want to inject them into IoC container) in the root package.

Answer (score 5):

In addition I would to add that by default, classes annotated with `@Component`, `@Repository`, `@Service`, `@Controller`, or a custom annotation that itself is annotated with @Component are the only detected candidate components.

You can change this behavior by applying custom filters which are  `include-filter` or `exclude-filter`

For example:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.vanilla">
      <context:exclude-filter 
                type="annotation"
                expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

It will exclude all @Repository annotations.