# cannot find the bean defined in xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to spring mvc, and I have a question that how to know if the tag  is scannning the correct package?
for example:
I have defined a tag named

```html
<context:component-scan base-package="spring.mvc"/>
```

and this package is located as below:
[image]

and when I define a bean in user-beans.xml, such as

```html
    <bean id="userService" class="spring.mvc.service.UserServiceImpl" />
```

user-beans.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    
    <context:component-scan base-package="spring.mvc"/>
    <context:annotation-config />
    
    <bean id="userService" class="spring.mvc.service.UserServiceImpl" />
    <bean id="userDao" class="spring.mvc.dao.UserDaoImpl" />
    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource" />
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="datasource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myusers" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

It seems like the bean cannot be found in the path I put in for class=""

The error is shown as below:

```html
19:44:19.399 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [spring.mvc.service.UserServiceImpl] for bean with name 'userService' defined in class path resource [config/user-beans.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: spring.mvc.service.UserServiceImpl
19:44:19.399 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@65f7a781: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory,userService,userDao,jdbcTemplate,datasource,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0]; root of factory hierarchy
19:44:19.433 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [spring.mvc.service.UserServiceImpl] for bean with name 'userService' defined in class path resource [config/user-beans.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: spring.mvc.service.UserServiceImpl
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1385) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:641) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1484) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1007) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
 at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158) [servlet-api.jar:3.1.FR]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183) [catalina.jar:8.5.15]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099) [catalina.jar:8.5.15]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:989) [catalina.jar:8.5.15]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4931) [catalina.jar:8.5.15]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5241) [catalina.jar:8.5.15]
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.5.15]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419) [catalina.jar:8.5.15]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) [catalina.jar:8.5.15]
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_131]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_131]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_131]
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_131]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: spring.mvc.service.UserServiceImpl
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.15]
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.15]
 at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:250) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:401) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1432) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1377) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
 ... 26 common frames omitted
```

Can someone explain how the component-scan works?

Thanks in advance

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807230/what-syntax-for-including-sub-packages-in-contextcomponent-scan

Comment: sorry I still dont get it

Comment: How about posting the error you are having.  it does not seem related to *context:component-scan*

Comment: edited! I have posted the error shown in the console!

Comment: Check to see if there is an earlier Exception when loading

Comment: no this is the first one

Comment: Can you check the deployed location and see if your class is deployed or not

Comment: how to check that? I am using eclipse. Is it the Deployment Assembly?

Comment: Which container are you using? Tomcat or jetty? Are you seeing .class files anywhere in `target` or in `classes` folders?

Comment: tomcat, and I dont see any .class files

Answer (score 0):

Verify the below two points in `UserServiceImpl` class:
1. check the package declaration in your class. It should be same as `spring.mvc.service`.
2.Check the class level annotation is added or not in your class (`@Component/@Service`).